# How can I pause a Java splash screen from a batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file, timeout, splash-screen

I have the simple batch file code, which is working:

```
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin
javac C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\batchFileTest\GUI.java
java -splash:images/splashImage.jpg GUI
```

However, it only takes like 1 second for my GUI class-file to load, and then the splash-screen immediately closes and launches the program.

I want to make the splash-screen wait for 5 seconds. My idea was to first execute the splash-screen *without* the class-file, to use `TIMEOUT`, and then to execute the class-file like this:

```
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin
javac C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\batchFileTest\GUI.java
java -splash:images/splashImage.jpg
TIMEOUT 5
java GUI
```

This isn't working correctly either. The splash-screen is then displayed for some milliseconds and is closed immediately. The command-line then waits for 5 seconds, and then the program is launched.

Any ideas on how to correctly do this from a batch file?

Comment: You could show your own splash screen by using an undecorated `JWindow`.  But why do you want to make your users wait longer than they need to to use your application? :-)

Comment: The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) says the splash screen is closed automatically once the first application window is shown.  Perhaps you can [put a delay](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) in your `public static void main` method before showing your first window if you really want to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks @Greg for the link! I have posted an answer here using your advice, where I am using `Thread.sleep` in the main method of the class called after the splash-screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Greg here, I have a solution where I am delaying the splash-screen from the main method using `Thread.sleep`.

---

Here is the batch file:

```
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin

javac C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\batchFileTest\GUI.java

java -splash:images/splashImage.jpg GUI
```

...and here is the class with the main method:

```
class GUI {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
         Thread.sleep(5000); // the parameter is in milliseconds

    catch(InterruptedException e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    /*
     * do whatever stuff here
     */
  }
} // end of GUI
```